# Visual Studio with SSDT version

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2015 installed and I need to connect to SQL Server 2017 to do schema compare. Can I connect to an SQL Server 2017 using Visual Studio 2015? It's something more related to SSDT version or I need to have Visual Studio 2017 or higher to connect to SQL Server 2017?

Comment: Well, what stops you to try and then tell us what has been your experience?

Comment: It's a really good question, but I don't have access right now to that machine and I want to make sure whatever we have will work, I just wanted to know if the VS version has to be in sync with the SQL version to perform the compare

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to access to the server and I can confirm that I was able to connect to SQL Server 2017 DBs using Visual Studio 2015, of course we need to have SSDT 2015 installed.